# Does using `std::string::c_str` return a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, string, dynamic-allocation

The documentation on `std::string::c_str` says:

"Returns a pointer to an array that contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (i.e., a C-string) representing the current value of the string object."

Is this array dynamically allocated on calling c_str? If not where does it come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C++2003 this is up to the standard library implementation. The actual storage for it is most likely managed by the instance of `std::string`. Some implementations may use the internal buffer, some may use a separate pre-allocated buffer. It is a constant-time accessor though, so the options available to a library implementation are limited.

You shouldn't mess around with that memory outside what you are allowed to do by the standard though as you may fall flat on your face with a different implementation of the standard library.

Interestingly for C++11 this is a bit more defined, it must point to the internal buffer and be a synonym for `std::string::data`.

Comment: I don't think allocating a new buffer is even possible, as copying the string to the new buffer would not be constant time, but O(n) on the length of the string. In practice I don't think I've heard of any behaviors other than the C++11 codified "return a const pointer to the internal buffer."

Comment: No, I can't see a way you could allocate either. It is possible that an implementation _could_ have two buffers it updates in parallel, but it is difficult to think of a reason **why**. Answer edited.

Comment: If you had one buffer that corresponded to the requirements of `c_str` there would be no practical reason to keep a second buffer in a different format. And definitely no reason that would justify doubling the memory overhead (and likely halving performance of every other operation).

Comment: All valid points. The only reason I _can_ think of is if you were ensuring that changes were not made to the internal buffer through the pointer returned by `c_str`. I assume something like that would only happen in a debug version of the standard library. `c_str` is most likely going to return the pointer to the internal buffer, the point was that it doesn't _have_ to before `C++11`.

Answer (score 4):

Prior to C++11 it's unspecified. The `string` object manages it. With C++11, it points to the `string` objects data.